# Como agregar una clase a una img con inview

Tags: javascript

Quiero agregar una clase a una img en el momento en que se muestre en pantalla, he intentado varias cosas pero soy novato, no se si se puede de otro modo que no sea con inView.
Este es el codigo:

```
<div class="bottom-page">
            <div class="triimagen">
                <img src="img/logos/logo1.png" alt="logo1" class="animate__logohtml">
                <img src="img/logos/logo2.png" alt="logo2">
                <img src="img/logos/logo3.png" alt="logo3">
            </div>
        </div>

<script>
    
    $(function() {
      $(".animate__logohtml").on('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartY) {
        if (visiblePartY === 'top') {
            const $el = $('.animate__logohtml');
            $el.addClass("animate__logohtml2");
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya está, tengo que comentar que estaba usando una libreria llamada inview.
Finalmente agrego la clase cuando se muestra la imagen en pantalla con:

```
  var el = document.querySelector('.animate__logohtml')

    var inview = InView(el, function(isInView) {
      if (isInView) {
        const $el = $('.animate__logohtml');
        $el.addClass("animate__logohtml2");
      }
    });
```